# Converting igraph to networkx for clustering

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, networkx, igraph, dendrogram

I have a python code which uses `igraph` library

```py
import igraph
edge =  [(0, 6), (0, 8), (0, 115), (0, 124), (0, 289), (0, 359), (0, 363), (6, 60), (6, 115), (6, 128), (6, 129), (6, 130), (6, 131), (6, 359), (6, 529), (8, 9), (8, 17), (8, 115)]
G = igraph.Graph(edges=edge, directed=False)
G.vs['label'] = nodes
G.es["weight"] = weights
dendrogram = G.community_edge_betweenness()
clusters = dendrogram.as_clustering()
membership = clusters.membership
out = pd.Series(membership, index=nodes)
```

and I need to convert it to `networkx` library.

```py
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph(edges)
dendrogram = nx.edge_betweenness_centrality(G)
clusters = nx.clustering(dendrogram)
membership = clusters.membership
out = pd.Series(membership, index=nodes)
```

However, `dendrogram` cannot be clustered in `networkx` library. Can someone help in replicating the `igraph` code to `networkx` clusters?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with `igraph`, so could I ask you to explain what `as_clustering()` does?  From looking at the documentation, it's not at all like the `nx.clustering` command (which returns the clustering coefficient for each node)

Comment: igraph has not been discontinued, this is simply not true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that "clustering" refers to two different things in network science.  It either refers to the clustering coefficient (fraction of triangles in the ego graph; [nx.clustering](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.cluster.clustering.html#networkx.algorithms.cluster.clustering)) or it refers to a group of nodes (a.k.a. data clustering, network community, node partition, etc).

In this case you are using igraph [community_edge_betweenness()](https://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.Graph-class.html#community_edge_betweenness) to hierarchically cluster your nodes, and then cut the dendrogram to create a node partition through [dendrogram.as_clustering()](https://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.clustering.VertexDendrogram-class.html#as_clustering).

The equivalent in networkx would be to use [girvan_newman](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.community.centrality.girvan_newman.html):

```
from networkx.algorithms.community.centrality import girvan_newman

nx_dendrogram = girvan_newman(G)
move_down_dendrogram = itertools.takewhile(lambda c: len(c) <= 4, nx_dendrogram)
for c in move_down_dendrogram:
    clustering_list = c
print(clustering_list)

membership = [0] * G.number_of_nodes()
for ic, cset in enumerate(clustering_list):
    for n in cset:
        membership[n] = ic
out = pd.Series(membership, index=nodes)
```

Comment: The above code works! Although, is there a method to identify the value for k, for selecting the most optimal number of communities which we want to create. My dataset contains about 1600 key words to be identified based on text matching within keywords.